# Не удается создать сеть между компьютерами

Tags: windows, администрирование

Подключение по сети происходит между XP и Windows 7, вчера все работало, сегодня стало выдавать такое сообщение: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал использовать политику безопасности, не удалось.
Из-за чего это произошло?

Comment: На Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите на русский.

Comment: Просто перегружать пробовали? Обновления какие-либо устанавливались? Что-нибудь в железе менялось?

Comment: перезагружав, обновления не ставились

Comment: Пингуется хотя бы?